# Spotify doesn't work after update to 15.04

Tags: 15.04, spotify

Yesterday I updated my Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04 but sadly i had to conclude that Spotify doesn't work anymore.
Today I installed 15.04 and Spotify again but nothing has changed - Spotify isn't working.

For installing Spotify I have used the instructions on this Page:

http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Spotify

How can I fix this?

(Sorry for my bad English, but I hope, this is understandable...)